# Xcode IBOutlet list has vanished

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, segue, iboutlet

xcode: I have set up the `IBOutlets` and the viewer and elements in the storyboard. But when I go to link them the IBOutlets are not listed. Yes I have set them up in the correct file, done this many times and linked many times. But today, for some reason my Segue layout changed and the `IBOutlets` `UIImageView` `UILabel` `UIButton` etc are not listed. I have also heard that it is not the best way to use the storyboard, that I would be better off not using it at all. So what is the alternative?

So two questions really. Where did my `IBOutlet` list go? And how can I do without the storyboard at all?

Comment: Try cleaning your project (Command + Shift + K), that usually will fix it. If not, close Xcode and reboot your machine. I've found Xcode to give me trouble when it has been opened for a long period of time (October 2013 retina MBP)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the custom class name you have given correctly or not for your storyboard

[image]

More over you dont want to use storyboard. use interface builder or do programatically.

Comment: Where do I go to learn it programatically? Everywhere I look, it is the storyboard everyone is talking about?